# Embedding another mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to embed a model in a mongoose schema. Here's what I have:

```
const People = {
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.objectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    locationId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.objectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Location'
    },
};

const Person = mongoose.model(
    'Person',
    new mongoose.Schema({
        ...People,
        gender: {
            type: String
        }
    })
);

const shmanian = await new Person({gender: 'other', userId:'someUserId', locationId: 'someLocationId'}).save();
```

The response I get is `{gender: 'other'}`

The problem is that people doesn't get populated when I create Person.

Comment: Can you give a sample document you want to keep?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You should embed an array of "Person" inside a model "People". For example,

```
const Schema = require("mongoose").Schema;
const model = require("mongoose").model;

const Person = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.objectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    locationId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.objectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Location'
    },
});

const People = new Schema({
    person: [Person]
});

module.exports = model("People", People);
```

Here, everytime you create a new Person, you can add it to the People model which contains an array of Person objects.

Comment: Thanks ,but I don't want an embedded schema, instead I just want to add another object into a schema

Answer (score 0):

Not a mongoose Problem.
`People` is undefined when you create the Object `Person`.
Thus it doesn't get populated.

Try switching both assignments.

Comment: Good catch, but in my actual code, it was in the correct order